# Open and position (duplicative) windows within GNOME from a script

Tags: shell-script, gnome, window-manager, wmctrl

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23280/how-does-one-open-a-new-window-from-the-shell-with-a-specific-size-and-position#) question shows how one can address a window by it's title, and then  position/resize it around.

Now to address a window there are five options:
- The window's ID: Changes on application restart => Useless
- The window's Title: Identical with the title of other windows => Useless
- The window's Namespace: Identical with the namespace of  other windows => Useless
- User selectable via clicking => The whole point of this is to be lazy, isn't it?
- The active window will be used => Maybe, but I feel like this could be unreliable **(?)**

What I want to do is to have a script open a bunch of applications, a few of them more than once (same or variable title) and position them on my desktops. Note the plural, I want some of them to go on another workspace aswell. `wmctrl` is capable of doing all that moving and resizing, but I'm not sure how to do the window selection.

Is there a way to get the Window ID right after starting the app? I know you can do this for the process ID, and `wmctrl` is able to get the PID for all apps I'm running, so is there a way to address a window using it's PID?

Alternatively, can `wmctrl` do the title matching in reverse? (The `--help` says the first match will be used, is it possible to use the most recently started (so I assume last) match instead?)

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Thought of this solution when the question was already almost done, so figured I'd self-answer. This works reliably, but there might be an easier way. If there's a way to do what I asked directly feel free to leave another answer.</sub>

## How to move and resize any application via script:

This example code should be self-explanatory (with its comments):

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0 gnome-calculator & # start app
cpid=$! # get process ID of said app
sleep 1 # give it a second to open the window (adjust to needs)
cwid=$(wmctrl -lp | grep " $cpid " | cut -d " " -f 1) # get window ID
wmctrl -i -r "$cwid" -e "0,3200,572,396,415" # move and resize!
# start the 2nd application...
DISPLAY=:0 sol &
cpid=$!
sleep 1
cwid=$(wmctrl -lp | grep " $cpid " | cut -d " " -f 1)
wmctrl -i -r "$cwid" -b "remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz" # un-maximize
wmctrl -i -r "$cwid" -t 1 # move to desktop 1 (2nd workspace)
wmctrl -i -r "$cwid" -e "0,1497,525,1342,860"
```

Just repeat for as many applications as you need, you can use `wmctrl -l` to find out the current geometry of the applications so you know what you wanna supply to the `-e` argument.

The format of the `-e` argument is: `<gravity>,<X_pos>,<Y_pos>,<width>,<height>`.